# PHP preg_replace single lines, ignore multiple lines possible?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have spent a few hours on this and cannot figure it out but due to my lack of preg_match knowledge even after studying it may be something easy.  This works in removing multiple lines into one line:

```
$string = preg_replace('/^\n|^[\t\s]\n/m', "", $string);
```

How can I reverse its function so that it ignores multiple lines and removes single lines of space?  So if the input is:

```
one

two



three
```

It would remove the space between one and two, but ignore the multiple spaces before three so the result would look like:

```
one
two



three
```

Thanks.

*EDIT POST*

Thanks guys.  3emad, your code works for my example.  I was wrong, I want this to work with code instead of just my text and when I tried using

```
// ----- limits -----



$new_limit = 7;       // maximum days in What's New section

$hot_limit = 20;      // top 20 most accessed links

$toprated_limit = 20; // top 20 most rated links 



// ----- bold the keyword in search result -----



$bold_keyword = 1;
```

it didn't remove the single line between the variables while ignoring the double space leading to the comments.

Comment: do each line contain only single word ?

Comment: no, they contain all types of data: numbers, symbols, spaces, tabs, and letters

Comment: check answer, hope it may help.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the regular expression:

```
[\r|\r\n](?=\w)
```

This works for your example, you can test it at: [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)

the secret was to use a positive look ahead matching, you can learn more about "look ahead" [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
$str = '// ----- limits -----



$new_limit = 7;       // maximum days in What\'s New section

$hot_limit = 20;      // top 20 most accessed links

$toprated_limit = 20; // top 20 most rated links 



// ----- bold the keyword in search result -----



$bold_keyword = 1;';

echo '<pre>';
echo preg_replace('/\r?\n(?=[\w|\$])/m','',$str);
echo '</pre>';
```

Helpful [PHP reference](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-Regex.html#10) for regular expressions

Comment: Thanks for your time but I get a PHP error when using the above code:    Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier '('

Comment: use this pattern: '/\r?\n(?=\w)/' i already added a php code version.

Comment: Thanks 3emad, it worked with my example but I was wrong.  I want it to work with variables like you can see in my edited post.  I would like for it to remove the space between the variables while leaving the multiple spaces before/after the comment sections.

Comment: please add the format on a pastebin, so it can run on ur actual text

Comment: All good?am trying to write you a more flexible which is not strictly to "$" and am still facing the problem of have double which am still analyzing

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is perfect solution for you, this will remove extra line + extra space + tabs

```
<?php
$input="this is  nimit

and friends
    this must be in single line.

@234 234234
                I have test this.
";
$input = str_replace(' ','_',$input);
$result = preg_replace('/\s+/','<br>',$input);
$result = str_replace('_',' ',$result);
echo $result;
?>
```